Can Narasimha mantras burn down the bad karmas?
I googled about the Narasimha 108 names and in google it said that it subdues negative karmas and burns the sins of an individual .
I would like to know is this really true that Narasimha 108 names does burn the sins and bad karmas done in this lifetime and others ?
Please try to provide some scriptural reference if possible.
